# How to query a nested attribute in SQLModel?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

I have these two tables named `User` and `UserRole`.

```py
import enum
from typing import List
from sqlmodel import Column, Enum, Field, Relationship, SQLModel


class UserRoleType(str, enum.Enum):
    admin = 'admin'
    client = 'client'


class UserRole(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'user_role'
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    type: UserRoleType = Field(
        default=UserRoleType.client,
        sa_column=Column(Enum(UserRoleType)),
    )

    write_access: bool = Field(default=False)
    read_access: bool = Field(default=False)

    users: List['User'] = Relationship(back_populates='user_role')


class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    username: str = Field(..., index=True)

    user_role_id: int = Field(..., foreign_key='user_role.id')
    user_role: 'UserRole' = Relationship(back_populates='users')
```

I can easily insert entries into the DB like so:

```py
async with get_session() as session:
    role = UserRole(description=UserRoleType.client)
    session.add(role)
    await session.commit()

    user = User(username='test', user_role_id=role.id)
    session.add(user)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(user)
```

And access the committed data with:

```py
    results = await session.execute(select(User).where(User.id == 1)).one()
```

Output: `(User(user_role_id=1, username='test', id=1),)`

**Notice that there's an `user_role_id`, but where's the `user_role` object?**

In fact, if I try to access it, it raises an error:

`AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'user_role'`

I also tried to pass the `role` instead of the `user_role_id` at the insertion of the `User`:

```py
    ...
    user = User(username='test', user_role=role)
```

But I got the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.`

Comment: how do you try to access `user_role` ?

Comment: Take a look at this issue https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/130 they told that problem was tracked, then the issue was closed, but I didn't tested to assure. To be honest, I quit using SQLModel, and stick to SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 3):

A few things first.

0. You did not include your import statements, so I will have to guess a few things.
1. You probably want the `User.user_role_id` and `User.user_role` fields to be "pydantically" optional. This allows you to create user instances without passing the role to the constructor, giving you the option to do so after initialization or for example by appending `User` objects to the `UserRole.users` list instead. To enforce that a user **must** have a role on the database level, you simply define `nullable=False` on the `User.user_role_id` field. That way, if you try to commit to the DB without having defined a user role for a user in any of the possible ways, you will get an error.
2. In your database insertion code you write `role = UserRole(description=UserRoleType.client)`. I assume the `description` is from older code and you meant to write `role = UserRole(type=UserRoleType.client)`.
3. You probably want your `UserRole.type` to be not nullable on the database side. You can do so by passing `nullable=False` to the `Column` constructor (**not** the `Field` constructor).
4. I will simplify a little by using blocking code (non-async) and a SQLite database.

This is how I would suggest you define the models:

```py
from enum import Enum as EnumPy
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Enum as EnumSQL
from sqlmodel import Field, Relationship, SQLModel


class UserRoleType(str, EnumPy):
    admin = 'admin'
    client = 'client'


class UserRole(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'user_role'

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    type: UserRoleType = Field(
        default=UserRoleType.client,
        sa_column=Column(EnumSQL(UserRoleType), nullable=False),
    )
    write_access: bool = Field(default=False)
    read_access: bool = Field(default=False)

    users: list["User"] = Relationship(back_populates='user_role')


class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    username: str = Field(..., index=True)

    user_role_id: Optional[int] = Field(
        foreign_key='user_role.id',
        default=None,
        nullable=False,
    )
    user_role: Optional[UserRole] = Relationship(back_populates='users')
```

Here is a little test function to show that it works as expected:

```py
from sqlmodel import Session, SQLModel, create_engine

# ... import User, UserRole, UserRoleType


def test() -> None:
    # Initialize database & session:
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)
    SQLModel.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session(engine)

    # Create the test objects:
    role = UserRole(type=UserRoleType.client)
    user = User(username='test', user_role=role)
    session.add(user)  # notice we don't need to add the `role` explicitly
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(user)

    # Do some checks:
    assert user.user_role.type is UserRoleType.client
    assert user.user_role_id == role.id and isinstance(role.id, int)
    assert role.users == [user]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

This passes without errors. The SQL output generated by the engine is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_role (
    type VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    write_access BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    read_access BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE user (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    username VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    user_role_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(user_role_id) REFERENCES user_role (id)
)

CREATE INDEX ix_user_username ON user (username)

INSERT INTO user_role (type, write_access, read_access) VALUES ('client', 0, 0)

INSERT INTO user (username, user_role_id) VALUES ('test', 1)

SELECT user.id, user.username, user.user_role_id 
FROM user 
WHERE user.id = 1

SELECT user_role.type AS user_role_type, user_role.id AS user_role_id, user_role.write_access AS user_role_write_access, user_role.read_access AS user_role_read_access 
FROM user_role 
WHERE user_role.id = 1

SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.user_role_id AS user_user_role_id 
FROM user 
WHERE 1 = user.user_role_id
```

PS: I know the question was posted a while ago, but maybe this still helps or helps someone else.